# aether-demo does not compile because of renaming of packages

Tags: maven, aether

I need to compile and execute the "aether-demo".

I didn't find a release of the "aether-demo", so I am using the snapshot as follows:

```
git clone git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/aether/aether-core.git
cd aether-core
mvn clean install

git clone git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/aether/aether-demo.git
cd aether-demo/
cd aether-demo-snippets/
mvn clean install
```

but it fails with:

```
[ERROR] /private/tmp/aether-demo/aether-demo-snippets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/aether/examples/manual/ManualRepositorySystemFactory.java:[33,40] cannot access org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultServiceLocator
[ERROR] class file for org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultServiceLocator not found
[ERROR] DefaultServiceLocator locator = new DefaultServiceLocator();
```

and other errors.

it tells that it does not find the class `"org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultServiceLocator"`

however, ManualRepositorySystemFactory.java has this import instead:

```
  import org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultServiceLocator;
```

why is so?
ManualRepositorySystemFactory.java is not importing that class from `org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal`. why mvn clean install tries to import it from this package?

moreover, the "aether-core" project has that file yet in another package: `org/eclipse/aether/impl/DefaultServiceLocator.java`

(and according to the git log, it has always been here)

so, what is happening?
is there a re-mapping of packages somewhere?

how to compile and execute the "aether-demo"?

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=406212

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=406212

> Benjamin Bentmann 2013-04-22 07:45:03 EDT
>
> The required dependencies to successfully run the examples has just been released and the
> corresponding CQs to consume them are still being processed. Until we
> have approval for these, you might want to take a look at
> https://github.com/bentmann/aether-demo which provides a preview of
> the update.