# Is there an API that allows to check a given maven repository for available updates on a specific package?

Tags: java, maven, auto-update

I have an application that I package as multiple jars. Each JAR are uploaded to a private maven repository on a local server.

Is there an API that exists that would allow me to check if an update is available for one of my JAR exclusiveley on my local maven repository, directly from the java application, not from maven?

I would use this to develop an "auto-update" feature in my application. I figure that since maven is already built to search and download dependencies, why re-invent the wheel?

Thanks!

Comment: Yep, you can use Aether. Take a look at the linked question for a complete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers to [Using maven programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084345/using-maven-programmatically) suggest looking at [Aether](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Aether/What_Is_Aether). Some of the [examples](http://git.eclipse.org/c/aether/aether-demo.git/tree/aether-demo-snippets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/aether/examples) certainly look like it's possible to do what you're after.

Comment: Seems like a good place to look! Apparently, Aether is the Maven artifact resolver, which is exactly what I am trying to do. I will give it a go!